# is it possible to return array with unknown output array shape in a guvectorize function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I'm wondering how I can return an array if I don't know it's size a priori with the numba guvectorize function.
I basically have a function which receives a vector and I return an array where it's size will change in the function. My issue is I cannot set the shape of the return array a priori.

for instance:

```
@guvectorize ([(float64[:],int64[:,:])], '(n),()->(n,2)')
def mysegmentation(Thresholding,StimSegments_time):
    count = 0
    for i in range(Thresholding.shape[0]-1):
        if Thresholding[i]==0. and Thresholding[i+1]==1.:
            StimSegments_time[count,0] = i 
        elif Thresholding[i]==1. and Thresholding[i+1]==0.:
            StimSegments_time[count,1] = i
            count += 1
```

Thresholding could have, let's say (1000) elements and StimSegments_time could have (5, 2) or (7, 2) or something else (x,2)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. But all I can help is that you cannot add a fixed number in the decorator (i.e., ->(n,2) is incorrect).

For that problem, people suggest to add a dummy array argument in the input and use its length in the output as discussed here:

[guvectorize not accepting new size variable](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2797)